# Get info from form and paste it to jsp

Tags: java, jsp, text

I have a `jsp` with a text field. I want to print out the text I inserted into text field, but have no idea how to do it.
JSP page:

```
<%@page contentType="text/html" pageEncoding="UTF-8"%>
<!DOCTYPE html>

<html>
    <head>
        <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8">
        <title>Return the name</title>
    </head>
    <body>
        <h1>Welcome</h1>
        Insert your text here:<br>
        <form name="txtForm" action="Main.java" method="post">
            <input type="text" name="txt">
            <input type="submit" value="Send">
        </form>
    </body>
</html>
```

And this is the `class(Main.java)` that is handling the JSP:

```
public class Main extends HttpServlet {

    protected void processRequest(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response)
        throws ServletException, IOException {

        String text = request.getParameter("txt");
        Date d = new Date();
        System.out.println("The name you enter is:" + text + "at the time : " + d);
    }
}
```

What I want is to take the info from the jsp through my class then print it out back on a the jsp. How can this be done? I tried to use `<%@ import ... >` and coudn't make it work. :(
Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The Action attribute value in form which you have written is wrong. Action value should match to the URL Pattern in Web.xml. For example, in JSP :

```
<form name="txtForm" action="NewServlet" method="post">
```

In Web.xml:

```
<servlet-mapping>
    <servlet-name>SimpleServlet</servlet-name>
    <url-pattern>/NewServlet</url-pattern>
</servlet-mapping> 
<servlet>
    <servlet-name>SimpleServlet</servlet-name>
    <servlet-class>complete Path of Servlet </servlet-class>
</servlet>
```

In the above  form action attribute value "NewServlet" will be mapped to the "" in web.xml. To write info back to JSP, in your servlet you can use PrintWriter Object.

```
String text = request.getParameter("txt");
Date d = new Date();
PrintWriter out = response.getWriter();
out.println("The name you enter is:" + text + "at the time : " + d);
```

Answer (score 0):

Firstly , this `form` definition might not work :

```
<form name="txtForm" action="Main.java" method="post">
```

In the `action` attribute you need to specify an URL such as `form.do` etc...
Then map the Servlet `Main.java` to this specific URL in the *web.xml*.

Try using the `PrintStream` to print it to the response.

```
response.getWriter.println("The name you enter is:" + text + "at the time : " + d);
```

When you do this , the response will be sent back to the browser.

Though ideally you should use a *JSP* for view .

You can send the request to a *JSP* and then print the request parameters using EL `${param.parameterName}`.

> i want is to take the info from the jsp thru my class then print it out back on a the jsp

This will be a bit lengthy exercise though . You need to dispatch the `request` from your Servlet class i.e. `Main.java` to a separate JSP setting the `request` attributes.

Comment: I put it into the java class? but i want to print my class action into the jsp ... (sorry if i ain't made my self clear...)...